¿Como imprimir caracteres extendidos desde un archivo txt en c++?
Explico el programa, hay un arreglo que mide 5 ancho y 3 de alto llamado cells, dónde se guarda cada línea de un archivo txt a través de la función void sprite, hay otra función que es una impresora que permite imprimir en cualquier posición de la consola con x'y. Después en la función pintarplayer se imprime el arreglo cells y se llama a la función imprimir para sumar x,y a a la filas y las columnas en cada caracter mientras se imprime cada línea habiendo una condicional que si hay un carácter 0 se imprime un carácter vacío, sino lo pinta normal.
Todo funciona bien en el codigo, si imprimo el archivo TXT de esta manera, lo imprime bien en consola.
00A00
0AAA0
AA0AA
Cuando lo imprimo con carácteres del ascii extendido me falta carácteres y los imprime de manera desorganizada, ya he verificado que el archivo txt este guardado en utf_8 sin BOM, que no hay espacios en blanco adicioanles en mi txt, etc.
Aqui esta el main
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#define COLOR_RED 12

using namespace std;

// Definiciones para el tamaño del sprite
const int WIDTH = 5;
const int HEIGHT = 3;

// Array para almacenar el sprite
char cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH] = {};

// Configura la página de códigos UTF-8
void SetConsoleUTF8()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
}

// Establece la posición del cursor y el color
void impresora(int x, int y)
{
    HANDLE hConsola = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsola, COLOR_RED);
    COORD XYPos;
    XYPos.X = x;
    XYPos.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsola, XYPos);
}

// Carga el sprite desde el archivo
void sprite()
{
    ifstream MyFile("spritenave.txt");
    if (MyFile.is_open())
    {
        int row = 0;
        string line;
        while (getline(MyFile, line) && row < HEIGHT)
        {
            for (int p = 0; p < line.length() && p < WIDTH; p++)
            {
                cells[row][p] = line[p]; // Guardar el carácter en cells
            }
            row++;
        }
        MyFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "El sprite no cargó :(" << endl;
    }
}

// Imprime el sprite en la consola
void pintarplayer(int x, int y)
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
        {
            if (cells[i][j] != '0') // No pintar si es '0'
            {
                impresora(x + j, y + i);
                cout << cells[i][j];  // Cambiado a cout para mejor manejo de caracteres
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleUTF8(); // Configura la página de códigos UTF-8
    bool Isgameover = false;

    // Carga el sprite
    sprite();

    // Coordenadas iniciales del sprite
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    while (!Isgameover)
    {
        // Imprime el sprite en la consola
        pintarplayer(x, y);

        // Salir del bucle (esto es solo para evitar un bucle infinito en este ejemplo)
        Isgameover = true;
    }

    return 0;
}

aqui esta el archivo spritenave.txt
00▲00
0(ø)0
▲¥0¥▲

esto es lo que me imprime la consola
    ▲
 ( ø)
  ▲ ¥
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.008 s
Press any key to continue.

Agradezco quien me ayude, estoy aprendiendo c++ en vacaciones por gusto y llevo con este problema desde hace 2 dias.

Sigo con el problema...Hice lo que decia la pagina que me mandaron y me sigue imprimiendo lo mismo..

Lo de imprimir caracteres Unicode debería estar funcionando. El problema es cómo los estás tratando en tu programa, en cells[row][p] = line[p]; // Guardar el carácter en cells. La codificación UTF8 es multibyte pero ahí solo guardas un byte. Entonces los caracteres que se representan con más de un byte no se guardan correctamente.

Asegúrate de estar usando wchar_t y funciones de salida de texto anchas
Cambia tu código para utilizar wchar_t en lugar de char y usa funciones como wcout para imprimir los caracteres extendidos. wchar_t es un tipo de dato que permite manejar caracteres de 2 bytes, que es útil para UTF-16 (la codificación que Windows maneja mejor).
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#define COLOR_RED 12

using namespace std;

// Definiciones para el tamaño del sprite
const int WIDTH = 5;
const int HEIGHT = 3;

// Array para almacenar el sprite
wchar_t cells[HEIGHT][WIDTH] = {};

// Configura la página de códigos UTF-8
void SetConsoleUTF8()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);
}

// Establece la posición del cursor y el color
void impresora(int x, int y)
{
    HANDLE hConsola = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsola, COLOR_RED);
    COORD XYPos;
    XYPos.X = x;
    XYPos.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsola, XYPos);
}

// Carga el sprite desde el archivo
void sprite()
{
    wifstream MyFile("spritenave.txt");
    MyFile.imbue(locale(locale::empty(), new codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>));
    if (MyFile.is_open())
    {
        int row = 0;
        wstring line;
        while (getline(MyFile, line) && row < HEIGHT)
        {
            for (int p = 0; p < line.length() && p < WIDTH; p++)
            {
                cells[row][p] = line[p]; // Guardar el carácter en cells
            }
            row++;
        }
        MyFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        wcout << L"El sprite no cargó :(" << endl;
    }
}

// Imprime el sprite en la consola
void pintarplayer(int x, int y)
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
        {
            if (cells[i][j] != L'0') // No pintar si es '0'
            {
                impresora(x + j, y + i);
                wcout << cells[i][j];  // Cambiado a wcout para mejor manejo de caracteres
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleUTF8(); // Configura la página de códigos UTF-8
    bool Isgameover = false;

    // Carga el sprite
    sprite();

    // Coordenadas iniciales del sprite
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    while (!Isgameover)
    {
        // Imprime el sprite en la consola
        pintarplayer(x, y);

        // Salir del bucle (esto es solo para evitar un bucle infinito en este ejemplo)
        Isgameover = true;
    }

    return 0;
}


Cambié char por wchar_t para manejar correctamente los caracteres extendidos.
Cambié ifstream por wifstream y utilicé una conversión de codificación con codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> para leer correctamente el archivo en UTF-8.
Cambié cout por wcout para manejar la salida de texto ancho.


Si imprimes los caracteres UTF-16, no deberías configurar la salida para UTF-8
